# Jquery Mobile Prepend not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I have function below that is for my mobile page. The alert fires when the DOM is ready but the prepend doesn't seem to work. Am I doing something wrong here? I am working on MVC 4.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function () {
    alert("This works but prepend doesn't");

    $('#Div').prepend('<div id="DivMenu">My Menu</div>');
});

<div id="Div">Hello</div>
```

UPDATE: The debugger shows as if it skips the prepend.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be using upper-case characters in your HTML element attributes, so:

```
$(document).one("pageinit", function () {
    alert("This works but prepend doesn't");

    $('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="div-menu">My Menu</div>');
});
<div id="wrapper">Hello</div>
```

Also when working with jQueryMobile you should be running the `pageinit` event using the one() command as you won't need it bound for multiple iterations.

Finally, get used to matching elements with `$.mobile.activePage.find("#wrapper");` so you don't need to crawl through the entire page to match an element - it will make your life a lot easier and make it easier to manage multiple pages.

Comment: I changed the id to a lowercase, but i doesn't seem to fix the problem. I also changed it to the one() command. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Are you able to select the element from your console, and does the element you are trying to select exist at the time you are trying to run it?

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I have found the problem! Thank you once again!